# Why is this Java function signature marked as wrong for overriding?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

Following situation

This Interface

```
public Interface ObjectService<T> {

  public T fromMNO(MNO<T> mno);

}
```

gets used by this abstract class

```
public AbstractObjectService<T> implements ObjectService<T> {

  public abstract T fromMNO (MNO<T> mno);

}
```

implemented in this class

```
public DummyService extends AbstractObjectService<DummyObj> {

  @Override
  public DummyObj fromMNO (DummyMNO mno) {
    //do stuff
    return new DummyObj();
  }

}
```

using this interface and interfaced object

```
public interface MNO<T> {}


public class DummyMNO implements MNO<DummyObj> {}
```

and a normal object

```
public class DummyObj {}
```

Now the problem is: `DummyService#fromMNO` gets flagged as not overrideable in VS Code bc of a type mismatch.

But as far as I understand `DummyService` with `T` as `DummyObj` results in `public DummyObj fromMNO (MNO<DummyObj> mno)` and `DummyMNO` IS A `MNO<DummyObj>`?

Am I wrong or is there something else fishy?

A "solution" would be to keep the "original type" and cast like this

```
@Override
  public DummyObj fromMNO<T> (MNO<DummyObj> mno) {
    DummyMNO d = (DummyMNO) mno;
    //do stuff
    return new DummyObj();
  }
```

which solves the problem of the error, but undermines the explicit type I wanted to achive.

Comment: As a short rule: You cannot change the signature of the method. So you have to stick to `MNO<DummyObj>` in your concrete service.

Comment: Imagine having another `class OtherObj` and another `class OtherMNO implements MNO<OtherObj>`. When using the interface (or the abstract class), I could easily have an instance of my `OtherMNO` serve as an argument to your method `fromMNO`. But your concrete service could not handle that. This is the reason, why the compiler forbids that.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose yep, you are correct. I need to add a type definition to the interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@Seelenvirtuose](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2563754/seelenvirtuose) pointed out, yes, it is impossible to change the signature of the function.

However it is possible to change the required type by using

```java
public Interface ObjectService<T, M extends MNO<T>> {

  public T fromMNO(M mno);

}

public AbstractObjectService<T, M extends MNO<T>> implements ObjectService<T, M> {

  public abstract T fromMNO (M mno);

}

public DummyService extends AbstractObjectService<DummyObj, DummyMNO> {

  @Override
  public DummyObj fromMNO (DummyMNO mno) {
    //do stuff
    return new DummyObj();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The fromMNO method that you are overriding in the DummyService class has a type mismatch with the fnoMNO in AbstractObjectService.

One of the solution is you already put in the question that is changing the argument in the DummyService class's method, you can do it like this...

```
public DummyService extends AbstractObjectService<DummyObj> {
  @Override
  public DummyObj fromMNO (MNO<DummyObj> mno) {
    return new DummyObj();
  }
}
```

Else, You can change the original type in the AbstractObjectService

```
public abstract class AbstractObjectService<T> implements ObjectService<T> {

  public abstract T fromMNO (DummyMNO mno);

}
```